# Angular Routing:Call different function on same module(or component) from different router links

Tags: angular, angular4-router

I have a module named Items and i navigate to its items.Component.ts form many router links.To track from which page we came an id can be passed along with router path.

```
this.router.navigate(['/items',id passed along with);
```

But i want to call different functions as per the page i came from before `ngOnit().` 
Ex. I want to call function A in itemscomponent if i navigated from Menu
or B if i navigated from Category

Also required navigation can be done from **both** module(or component) **html file** or component.ts(view model)
How can i achieve this in angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use queryParams and send 1 from menu page and 2 from category, and after navigate you can execute functions related to you query params

```
   this.router.navigate(['/items'],id, { queryParams: { functionToexecute: 1  } });
```

and in your itemsComponent:

```
 constructor(
   private route: ActivatedRoute,
   private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {
   this.route
    .queryParams
    .subscribe(params => {
     if (params['functionToexecute'] === 1){ call functionA} else{call 
      function B}
   });
 }
```